# How to get an HP and Canon printer to work in Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, troubleshooting, printer

After installing Snow Leopard onto my Mac Pro, I found I was unable to print to either one of my printers, and HP LaserJet, or a Canon iR C3220-C1. So how do you get them to print again?  I'm answering my own question below because I couldn't find anything to help getting mine working.

Comment: Did you have this solved before you even started typing the question?

Comment: Yeah, but it won't let me accept it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HP was simple. First I ran software update and installed the HP printer driver update. However, it still said it needed updated software after this, so I removed the printer and reinstalled it. It printed perfectly after this.

The Canon was a bit tougher. I downloaded and installed the Canon printer driver update, but this probably didn't make a difference because the iR C3220 is not a supported printer on the Apple site.

Next I downloaded a fresh copy of the driver from here [imagePASS-C1v2.1_PPD_Intel_MacOSX.hqx](http://www.usa.canon.com/opd/controller?act=OPDSoftwareAct&fcategoryid=2307&modelid=9027)

It installed correctly, and I removed the printer and reinstalled. Tip: the printer doesn't show up using Appletalk anymore, so when you add the printer, choose *IP* on the top, select *Line Printer Daemon - LPD*. Type in the printer's IP address. For the Queue, type in *print*. Under Print Using, choose the *Canon iR C3220-C1* ppd.

It still wouldn't work, so I checked the cups error log file. From terminal, type:

> tail /var/log/cups/error_log

The error I was receiving was:

> Filter
>   "/usr/libexec/cups/filter/fierycupsfilter"
>   for printer "_11_22_33_44" not owned
>   by root

The fix was easy enough:

> sudo chown root:wheel
>   /usr/libexec/cups/filter/fierycupsfilter

I had to remove the printer and add it again, but after that it worked.

I found absolutely nothing when searching for this on the internet, so hopefully this helps someone else who may be using this combination. There may be similar problems with other fiery-based printers.

Answer (score 1):

Apple just released [updated Snow Leopard printer drivers for HP printers](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9137905/HP_adds_Snow_Leopard_printer_drivers_after_customer_complaints) today (9/11/2009).  You can install them through Apple Software Update.